# Python threads exit early

Tags: python, multithreading, keyboard

I'm trying to create 3 hotkeys which execute functions when pressed.

The code for each hotkey is run by a thread, e.g.:

```
import keyboard
from threading import Thread

def start_tracking(project_id):
    do API Call

def end_tracking():
    do API Call

def started(project_id,hotkey):
    start_tracking(project_id)
    keyboard.remove_hotkey(hotkey)
    keyboard.add_hotkey(hotkey, ended, args=([project_id,hotkey]))

def ended(project_id,hotkey):
    end_tracking()
    keyboard.remove_hotkey(hotkey)
    keyboard.add_hotkey(hotkey, started, args=([project_id,hotkey]))

#Hotkeys

t1 = Thread(target=keyboard.add_hotkey("F1", started, args=([project1,"F1"])))
t2 = Thread(target=keyboard.add_hotkey("F2", started, args=([project2,"F2"])))
t3 = Thread(target=keyboard.add_hotkey("F3", started, args=([project3,"F3"])))

t1.start()
t2.start()
t3.start()
```

When I run the code, it just finishes the program with no message or error. If I run the code in the debugger and step over each thread (t1, t2, t3), they actually start and work as intended.

Since the functions executed in the threads are endless loops (started() is calling ended() and vice versa and thus the threads should never finish), why do they exit early?

Comment: I'm not sure what you expect to happen. Surely you intend this program to wait for you to press the function keys. Why do you need threads?

Comment: nothing in the above code is running any thread whatsoever.

Comment: Hi @quamrana, some context: The idea is to create 3 hotkeys which start time tracking for 3 different projects. You can assign each project on a hotkey. keyboard.add_hotkey waits for an event (pressing the hotkey) and invokes a callback. The callback is an API call which starts the time tracking for the project (with it's id passed into the event function's arg). We now have an event listening for a key press. However, whenever you press the key the timer is restarted. So what I do in the code is remove the event and add a new one subsequently which in case of the key press stops the timer.

Comment: I then call ended() with started() and vice versa so that the hotkeys remain usable all the time, the event is thus stuck in an endless loop.

I need the threads because if I execute the events one after the other, after calling the first event the next ones are never called because the code is stuck in the aforementioned endless loop.

@AhmedAEK

why not? I'm creating the threads in the code and then starting them?
atleast in the debugger they function when run step by step.

Comment: Why don't you use something like `keyboard.wait()` to wait for key presses instead of threads?

Comment: Because keyboard.wait() waits for a key press and then exits the code. I need something that can continuously execute code when pressing a key (ergo an event listener, such as keyboard.add_hotkey).
Again the reason why I use threading is because I don't know how to solve my design problem of executing the endless loop and all the events in parallel. Since if one event is stuck in a loop, it won't execute the others. That's why I run them with multiple threads.

It's a design problem (I am quite inexperienced and don't know how to design a more elegant solution)

Comment: The documentation implies that `keyboard.wait()` will wait forever.

Comment: I tried it yesterday but it didn't work for me